# Proving root of polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

When $P(x) = ax^3 +bx^2+cx+d$ is divided by $(x-\alpha)$ the remainder is $p$, and when divided by $(x+\alpha)$ the remainder is $-p$.

Prove that $\alpha = pb/(dc-ad)$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site ! You must understand that a lot of people are ready to help you **provided** that you tell what you already tried, expalin where you are stuck and so on.

Comment: I dont think that i am doing this right at all. I expanded the equations for $P(\alpha)$ and $P(-\alpha)$. I then used simultaneous equations and subbed $p$ into $-p$ and simplified to get $\alpha = -d/(b+c)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I think there's a typo, it should be $\alpha = pb/(bc-ad)$. Take for example $P(x) = x^3 + x^2 - 3x - 4$ and $\alpha = p= 2$.

Then it's unclear how you got it that way, from your description your approach seem to be correct and I guess that you've miscalculated somewhere.

What you have is:

$$P(\alpha) = a\alpha^3 + b\alpha^2 + c\alpha + d = p$$
$$P(-\alpha) = -a\alpha^3 + b\alpha^2 - c\alpha + d = -p$$

Then adding and subtracting you get after dividing by two:

$$b\alpha^2 + d = 0$$
$$a\alpha^3 + c\alpha = p$$

From the first you get $\alpha^2 = -d/b$ and inserting it into the second you get:

$$c\alpha - a\alpha d/b = p$$
$$\alpha(c-ad/b) = p$$
$$\alpha = p/(c-ad/b) = pb/(bc - ad)$$

Then of course you should sort out the special cases where $\alpha=0$ or  $b=0$...

Comment: yes you were right. I did do a typo. Thanks